# Does safari on iOS update automatically? Outside of iOS updates?

Tags: ios, safari

I realize that safari is updated when iOS is updated. But is it ever updated silently, like chrome or firefox, for more minor additions? Say for bugs in webkit/nitro.

Or is it more like the stock android browser, or internet explorer? Which only are updated when the platforms they reside on are updated.

Answer (score 2):

Safari is only updated with iOS updates. As far as I know, there is no background updating, and updates only happen along with iOS updates.

[image: Safari updates for iOS 6]

Above is a screenshot from the new features of iOS 6 - listed is Safari as one of those updates.

Comment: I realize that safari is updated when iOS is updated. What I'm really trying to find out is whether it's ever updated silently, like chrome or firefox, for more minor additions. Say for bugs in webkit/nitro.

Comment: I'll edit the question with that clarification.